# Dilemma in Theory of Superposition of Electric potential

Tags: electrostatics, potential, potential-energy

Electric potential is the amount of work done in bringing a unit charge from infinity to a point. Here we take infinity as a reference point.
 The unit charge might have higher or lower potential energy depending on the value of electric potential(volts).

But the "principle of superposition" says that a charge might have higher or lower potential energy depending on the number of charges around it because the potential, according to formula is the sum of *volts* of all the charges around (Neither my book nor the principle directly says that but this is what i could conclude from the formula given for sysem of charges). This doesnt make any sense to me. Is this conclusion correct?

The same question also applies to the concept of superposition of gravitational potential. How could the potential energy of a mass be higher just because there are many masses around it?

Comment: You say that electric potential is the amount of work done in bringing a unit charge from infinity to a point. The work depends on the field, that depend on the other charges around. I don't understand how it should be otherwise.

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski while your comment makes sense, i dont understand this from a prcatical point of view. It basically means that potential energy of an object in gravitational field is higher because many objects sorround it. If that object falls it should release more energy *just* because of the number of masses around it. This doesnt make sense.......

Comment: Are you thinking of the potential energy as something inside/belonging to a mass? so confused about how adding other masses near it could change that potential energy? please clarify what exactly is causing confusion

Comment: @innisfree........sorry to bother you. I think i got the answer.....As Electric Potential depend on the electric field the number of charges change the potential of the point and is the sum of potential of all charges. Incase of Gravitational Potential, the M in the formula is mass of earth, so it technically means the mass sourrounding the point, probably this is why we usually dont talk about *theory of superposition of gravitational potential* . Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

After waiting for a long time, i tried to find the answer and i think i got the answer.....

As Electric Potential depend on the electric field the number of charges change the potential of the point and is the sum of potential of all charges. Incase of Gravitational Potential, the M in the formula is mass of earth, so it technically means the mass sourrounding the point, probably this is why we usually dont talk about theory of superposition of gravitational potential .

Is this correct?

Answer (score -3):

If I understood you right I may have an answer to your problem. The potential energy depends on the electric potential created by the charges just like you described. A bigger potential maybe created by more charges or just one bigger charge leads to an higher potential Energy. The problem is, when it comes to more than two charges the math gets tricky that's why your books might left it out.

Comment: can you say the same about gravitational potential?

Comment: For the gravitational potential the potential energy is is defined slightly different (same for different charges). There the potential energy is defined by the amount of work done bringing the mass to infinity.

Comment: for electric charges it is also defined as  the amount of work done in bringing the charge from infinity. after all, infinity is just a reference point, what i really want to ask is whether the potential will be affected by the masses sorrounding it ?